# Mysql Json - Fetch perticular object from json array on the basis of given id

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysql-5.7

I have a field of json type named 'user' in 'users' table containing following data

```
[{"uid":"213", "name":"Tim", "email":"user1@example.com"}, {"uid":"214", "name":"Cook", "email":"user2@example.com"}, {"uid":"215", "name":"Peter", "email":"user3@example.com"}, {"uid":"216", "name":"Jhon", "email":"user4@example.com"}]
```

I want to fetch user object of given `uid`
used this Query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE json_extract(`user`, "$[0].uid") = "213"
```

but it returns entire array in user field
result that i want is - `{"uid":"213", "name":"Tim", "email":"user1@example.com"}`

tried this also

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE json_extract(`user`, "$[*].uid") = "213"`
```

but it returns `NULL`

How to find particular object of given uid?

Comment: Where did you learn that: `WHERE json_extract(` ???

Comment: Forget my last comment! Your Problem is that the content of the field is more then one user in the json data, so you will get always all, because MYSQL return the content of the field, no matter how you have selected it via MYSQL. Why is more than one user information in the json-example???

Comment: Hi @JustOnUnderMillions. I got that data from api. Users of one company are in one field. isn't it possible to get single object from that array in the field?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `JSON_EXTRACT(`user`, "$[0].uid")"` in `SELECT` too.

Try

```
SELECT *, JSON_EXTRACT(`user`, "$[0].uid") FROM users WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`user`, "$[0].uid") = "213"
```

[Referance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)